# Is ISO/IEC 14882:2011 the final draft?

Tags: c++, c++11

Sorry but I just want to be sure, since I'm thinking about buying it at some point.  Is this it?  Will there be any subsequent changes to C++11, or is that standard now, officially, the C++ language? (Not counting the eventual C++18, C++2x, etc. of course.)  Wikipedia says

> C++11 was published as "ISO/IEC 14882:2011"[4] in September 2011

But I'm not familiar enough with this process to really be sure of the answer to my question.

Comment: Anything you actually buy from a standards organization will be the complete and correct standard.

Comment: @David Ok thank you, that makes sense of course--it's just that the review process has been so long and there have been so many drafts... My poor head was confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version you see now is the finished ratified specification. It is no longer a draft.

They published in the finished spec September 2011" referred to in Wikipedia is when they published the finished spec, and also when it was formally given the name "C++11".

Prior to that, when it was still a draft, it was referred to as C++0x.

See also: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html

Answer (score 6):

Yes, ISO/IEC 14882:2011 is the finished standard (not a draft anymore).